# Django (?) really slow with large datasets after doing some python profiling

Tags: python, django, optimization

I was comparing an old PHP script of mine versus the newer, fancier Django version and the PHP one, with full spitting out of HTML and all was functioning faster. MUCH faster to the point that something has to be wrong on the Django one.

First, some context: I have a page that spits out reports of sales data. The data can be filtered by a number of things but is mostly filtered by date. This makes it a bit hard to cache it as the possibilities for results is nearly endless. There are a lot of numbers and calculations done but it was never much of a problem to handle within PHP.

UPDATES:

- After some additional testing there is nothing within my view that is causing the slowdown. If I am simply number-crunching the data and spitting out 5 rows of rendered HTML, it's not that slow (still slower than PHP), but if I am rendering a lot of data, it's VERY slow.
- Whenever I ran a large report (e.g. all sales for the year), the CPU usage of the machine goes to 100%. Don't know if this means much. I am using mod_python and Apache. Perhaps switching to WSGI may help?
- My template tags that show the subtotals/totals process anywhere from 0.1 seconds to 1 second for really large sets. I call them about 6 times within the report so they don't seem like the biggest issue.

Now, I ran a Python profiler and came back with these results:

```
Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 3074 to 20 due to restriction 

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  2939417   26.290    0.000   44.857    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/tokenize.py:212(generate_tokens)
  2822655   17.049    0.000   17.049    0.000 {built-in method match}
  1689928   15.418    0.000   23.297    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:515(__new__)
 12289605   11.464    0.000   11.464    0.000 {isinstance}
   882618    9.614    0.000   25.518    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:1447(_fix)
    17393    8.742    0.001   60.798    0.003 /usr/lib/python2.5/tokenize.py:158(tokenize_loop)
       11    7.886    0.717    7.886    0.717 {method 'accept' of '_socket.socket' objects}
   365577    7.854    0.000   30.233    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:954(__add__)
  2922024    7.199    0.000    7.199    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/inspect.py:571(tokeneater)
   438750    5.868    0.000   31.033    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:1064(__mul__)
    60799    5.666    0.000    9.377    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:241(__init__)
    17393    4.734    0.000    4.734    0.000 {method 'query' of '_mysql.connection' objects}
  1124348    4.631    0.000    8.469    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py:44(force_unicode)
   219076    4.139    0.000  156.618    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py:700(_resolve_lookup)
  1074478    3.690    0.000   11.096    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:5065(_convert_other)
  2973281    3.424    0.000    3.424    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:718(__nonzero__)
   759014    2.962    0.000    3.371    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:4675(__init__)
   381756    2.806    0.000  128.447    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:231(__get__)
   842130    2.764    0.000    3.557    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.5/decimal.py:3339(_dec_from_triple)
```

tokenize.py comes out on top, which can make some sense as I am doing a lot of number formatting. Decimal.py makes sense since the report is essentially 90% numbers. I have no clue what the built-in method `match` is as I am not doing any Regex or similar in my own code (Something Django is doing?) The closest thing is I am using itertools ifilter.

It seems those are the main culprits and if I could figure out how to reduce the processing time of those then I would have a much much faster page.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could start on reducing this? I don't really know how I would fix this the tokenize/decimal issues without simply removing them.

Update: I ran some tests with/without filters on most of the data and the result times pretty much came back the same, the latter being a bit faster but not much to be the cause of the issue. What is exactly going on in tokenize.py?

Comment: It is impossible to suggest something useful without your view code and profiling guidance.

Comment: Alex: My view is fairly simple. It pulls up an initial list of entries,  then if the report is modified it adds some filters. That's really it. My template then regroups the dataset into two sections and then loop through it all, calling templatetags along the way (But I've timed the template tags to execute in 0.1 -> 0.5 seconds .. these templatetags are the subtotals/totals of the report so that execution time is ok on huge sets of data.)

Comment: @Bartek: Please do not comment on your own question.  It's your question, you can update it to contain all the relevant facts.

Comment: Try to extract the problem out of the templating system: write a standalone bit of code to query the records and print the results in a simpler form but with the same data.  If that's still slow, add it to the question so we can see what you're doing.  If that's fast, then you've narrowed in on the problem a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a lot of things to assume about your problem as you don't have any type of code sample.

Here are my assumptions: You are using Django's built-in ORM tools and models (i.e. sales-data = modelobj.objects().all() ) and on the PHP side you are dealing with direct SQL queries and working with a query_set.

Django is doing a lot of type converting and casting to datatypes going from a database query into the ORM/Model object and the associated manager (objects() by default).

In PHP you are controlling the conversions and know exactly how to cast from one data type to another, you are saving some execution time based on that issue alone.

I would recommend trying to move some of that fancy number work into the database, especially if you are doing record-set based processing - databases eat that kind of processing from breakfast.  In Django you can send RAW SQL over to the database: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql

I hope this at least can get you pointed in the right direction...

Comment: Thanks. You're right, that does make sense. I was seeing queries executing fine and with low MS so I never considered that. The issue is of course, that the ORM is lovely and keeps the code much cleaner in cases like this so I would enjoy not having to go down that road if at all possible. The number processing I am doing is not complex (Add these three numbers, multiply this) and then I am simply outputting them using the |intcomma and |floatformat:2 django filters so I'm not sure if that's the core of the issue.

Comment: The issue you may be running into regarding the adding numbers, multiplying numbers is quantity of records.  If you keep the number of returned records lower, it will reduce memory overhead and the amount of time it takes to process that data.  Keep this in mind: you cannot make an application faster, you can only make it do less work.

Comment: Unfortunately in some severe cases, the user wants a report of yearly sales data and I can't really keep the records lower. .. :)

Comment: I also don't think that your performance bottleneck is in the template engine.  You could use some of the timers around key calls in your view to try and find the slowest portions of python code and improve from there.

Comment: I've done some very basic testing using the time module as well and there was nothing within my view or template tags that was exceeding huge processing times. Even more proof that the rendering may be the issue is that if I select a "Totals Only" filter for my report, which as you guessed will only show totals, it will display much more quickly. For my page to hit the first templatetag for subtotals, it takes about 10 seconds when I am showing all the data.

Answer (score 2):

"tokenize.py comes out on top, which can make some sense as I am doing a lot of number formatting. "

Makes no sense at all.

See http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html.

> The tokenize module provides a lexical
>   scanner for Python source code,
>   implemented in Python

Tokenize coming out on top means that you have dynamic code parsing going on.

AFAIK (doing a search on the Django repository) Django does not use tokenize.  So that leaves your program doing some kind of dynamic code instantiation.  Or, you're only profiling the **first** time your program is loaded, parsed and run, leading to false assumptions about where the time is going.

You should **not** ever do calculation in template tags -- it's slow.  It involves a complex meta-evaluation of the template tag.  You should do all calculations in the view in simple, low-overhead Python. Use the templates for presentation only.

Also, if you're constantly doing queries, filters, sums, and what-not, you have a data warehouse.  Get a book on data warehouse design, and follow the data warehouse design patterns.

You must have a central fact table, surrounded by dimension tables.  This is very, very efficient.

Sums, group bys, etc., are can be done as `defaultdict` operations in Python.  Bulk fetch all the rows, building the dictionary with the desired results.  If this is too slow, then you have to use data warehousing techniques of saving persistent sums and groups separate from your fine-grained facts.  Often this involves stepping outside the Django ORM and using RDBMS features like views or tables of derived data.

Comment: Can you tell me why I shouldn't do any calculations (basic addition to sum up numbers) in templatetags? After your post, I kind of figured out a more efficient way to do what my templatetags are doing which is kind of useful but they are still not the bottleneck. Atleast it will shave off a few seconds of processing time :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with large sets of data, you can also save a lot of CPU and memory by using the [ValuesQuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields) that accesses the query results more directly instead of creating a model object instance for each row in the result.

It's usage looks a bit like this:

```
Blog.objects.order_by('id').values()
```

Answer (score 1):

In such a scenario the database is often the bottleneck. Also, using an ORM might result in sub-optimal SQL queries.

As some pointed out it's not possible to tell what the probem really is, just with the information you provided.

I just can give you some general advice:

- If your view is working with related model objects, consider using [select_related()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4). This simple method might speed up the queries generated by the ORM considerably.
- Use the [Debug Footer Middleware](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/766/) to see what SQL queries are generated by your views and what time they took to execute.

PS: Just fyi, I had once a fairly simple view which was very slow. After installing the [Debug Footer Middleware](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/766/) I saw that around 500! sql queries were executed in that single view. Just using [select_related()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4) brought that down to 5 queries and the view performed as expected.